# using Diab, dcc 5.9.4 to compile a windows executable

Tags: embedded, cross-compiling, wind-river-workbench

I'm doing some experiments with an evaluation version of the WindRiver dcc diab compiler. I would like to do some testing on my Windows PC. 
However I think I have the wrong target setup.

I've got as far as using the 'dctrl -t' command to get the list of target architectures, but selecting options so far hasn't produced anything i can run on windows.
I'm simply doing:

```
dcc main.c -o main.exe
```

Am I missing a step?
do I have the wrong target?
or is it simply not possible to create windows binaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the Diab compiler targets a free-standing environment, so would not produce a Windows executable.  Moreover x86 is not a supported target processor in any case; see the [product brief](http://www.windriver.com/products/product-overviews/PO_Diab_Compiler_1211.pdf).

The compiler is intended for use with VxWorks, though can be separately licensed.  The toolchain includes an instruction-set simulator for executing target code in a simulated environment, and if you are using VxWorks, that includes a [VxWorks simulator](http://www.windriver.com/evaluations/gpp-ve/).

If you want to build your code as a native Windows application; you will have to use a Windows targeted compiler.  I suggest MinGW/GCC since WindRiver support both their own WindRiver/Diab compiler and GCC for Vxworks development, and they share a great deal of commonality with respect to compiler switches and extension syntax.